# Compile error in import statement

Tags: scala, scalatest

My Scala test class won't compile because of an import statement for a Java class. This is the import statement:

```
import com.company.a.b.c.ClassName
```

And I get this error:

```
scala: object b is not a member of package com.company.a
```

The class is in the correct package and the IDE (IntelliJ) shows no errors/warnings. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the references class have the correct `package` statement at the beginning of the file?

Comment: Yes. It's being used by other Java classes which work well. I'm new to Scala and currently trying out Scala test so it's probably something I missed.

Comment: Please show more code.

Comment: Not sure that would help unfortunately. I have my scala test in `package com.company.a.b.d.scala` with some junit and scalatest imports followed by the import mentioned in the question. The class (ClassName) is in the correct package.

Comment: And if you use the full qualified name if your code instead of the import, do you still get the error ?

Comment: And are you sure that the class is in the runtime classpath ?

Comment: It's possible that the class path your IDE is using is different from what u are using to compile the code where it is breaking. How are you compiling it where the error is occurring?

Comment: Are you compiling with IDEA or through terminal/sbt/scalac?

Comment: I'm compiling with IDEA

Comment: @Michael Try to clear IDEA cache - File/Invalidate Caches

Comment: Good idea @AlexIv and was hoping it works. No luck however.

Comment: Do you really have `scala` in your package declaration? Not I've just tried it and IntelliJ got crazy.

Comment: I do - the reason is that I have a class with the same name one level up. We want to try porting some of our unit tests to BDD Scala tests. I prefer to have them in a `*.scala` package than changing the class names. Having said that, I tried renaming the package to remove `scala` but still got the same errors.